# Different tools available for creating data pipelines

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, data-pipeline

I need to create data pipelines in hadoop. I have data import, export, scripts to clean data set up and need to set it up in a pipeline now.

I have been using Oozie for data import and export schedules but now need to integrate R scripts for data cleaning process as well.

I see falcon is used for the same.

1. How to install falcon in cloudera?
2. What other tools are available to create data pipelines in hadoop?

Comment: you can invoke R from a shell action in oozie.

Comment: Code if you need `export engine=$1
export hive_db=$2
export Rcode=NeighborGroupingState.R

Rscript --vanilla ${Rcode} $1 $2  --hiveconf tez.credentials.path=${HADOOP_TOKEN_FILE_LOCATION} --hiveconf mapreduce.job.credentials.binary=${HADOOP_TOKEN_FILE_LOCATION}`

Answer (score 1):

2) I'm tempted to answer nifi from Hortonworks, since this [post on linkedin](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/nifi-vs-falcon-oozie-birender-saini) it has grown a lot and it's very close to replace oozie. When I'm writing this answer the difference between oozie and nifi is the place where they run: nifi on external cluster and oozie into hadoop.